# which start_kernel() function is used?

Tags: linux-kernel

When I was going through the linux kernel code I found the entry point to kernel as i386_start_kernel() function which is doing all early setup and then start_kernel() is called.
 Now when I searched for start_kernel() I found it is defined in several .c files as such: 
           Bootp.c, Main.c under /boot and again Main.c under /init.

As per my understanding it should be from Main.c under /init. But still I am not so cleared about it. It would be great if someone can confirm which start_kernel() is called  or explain which start_kernel() is for what?

Comment: In `arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S` you have jump to `i386_start_kernel()`. `i386_start_kernel()` is defined in `arch/x86/kernel/head32.c`. `i386_start_kernel()` function calls `start_kernel()`, which is defined at `init/main.c`.

Comment: Seems like this question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589845/what-are-the-first-operations-that-the-linux-kernel-executes-on-boot).

Answer (score 5):

The `start_kernel` from the `init/main.c` is a entry point to the generic kernel code. All other `start_kernel` functions which you can find in the linux kernel soure code, do architecture-specific job.